# Class Methods vs Instance methods in this particular code

Tags: ruby

My class looks like this...

```
class ThirdPartyServiceImport
  def posts
    execute!('12313', 'EFewfeHUIfaieuh8328')
  end

  def comments
    execute!('333434', 'EwaefawefFewfeHUIh8328')
  end


  private

  def execute!(identifier, key)
    client = ThirdPartyClient.new(key)

    client.run_query(identifier: identifier)
  end
end
```

Should i be using class methods?  If so, why?

This code is responsible for hitting a 3rd party API and importing content from it.  For the example here I'm just pretending the content that would be returned by my methods will be Posts and Comments.

This content is data my app depends on and periodically these methods/this class will be used to refresh the data.

Comment: What does this code actually do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instance methods are fine, here is an excellent blog post which goes over some advantages of using instances instead of spamming class methods.

http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/11/14/why-ruby-class-methods-resist-refactoring/